# How do I make two different screens look like doing a one variable check in css and html? (look below)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i am creating a website for my nft collection, with a whitelist sale and a public sale. My problem, once the user is logged in with his metamask account, he should put a check if his wallet is whitelisted. If your wallet belongs to the whitelist, then it appears as a screen and you can proceed with the purchase of the NFT, if your wallet does not belong to the whitelist you will have another screen that you have to pass to buy the NFT. Can someone help me?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { connect } from "./redux/blockchain/blockchainActions";
import { fetchData } from "./redux/data/dataActions";
import * as s from "./styles/globalStyles";
import styled from "styled-components";

const truncate = (input, len) =>
 input.length > len ? `${input.substring(0, len)}...` : input;

const whitelistedAddresses = ['here the first address', 'here the second address']; 


const whitelisted = "Congratulations, you are whitelisted!";

const notWhitelisted = "You are not whitelisted";



export const StyledButton = styled.button`
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: none;
 background-color: var(--secondary);
 padding: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: var(--secondary-text);
 width: 100px;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px -2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px -2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px -2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
 :active {
   box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
 }
`;

export const StyledRoundButton = styled.button`
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: none;
 background-color: var(--primary);
 padding: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: var(--primary-text);
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px -2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px -2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px -2px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
 :active {
   box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
 }
`;

export const ResponsiveWrapper = styled.div`
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: stretched;
 align-items: stretched;
 width: 100%;
 @media (min-width: 767px) {
   flex-direction: row;
 }
`;

export const StyledLogo = styled.img`
 width: 200px;
 @media (min-width: 767px) {
   width: 300px;
 }
 transition: width 0.5s;
 transition: height 0.5s;
`;

export const StyledImg = styled.img`
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 border: 4px dashed var(--secondary);
 background-color: var(--accent);
 border-radius: 100%;
 width: 200px;
 @media (min-width: 900px) {
   width: 250px;
 }
 @media (min-width: 1000px) {
   width: 300px;
 }
 transition: width 0.5s;
`;

export const StyledLink = styled.a`
 color: var(--secondary);
 text-decoration: none;
`;



 function App() {
   const whitelistedAddresses = ['0x74be05EDACC9c0CcEb78BC0fCB76315069b6F411', '0x7490ED764e113F9283507E8401b011c8eF8F2Dbe']; 
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const blockchain = useSelector((state) => state.blockchain);
   const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);
   const [claimingNft, setClaimingNft] = useState(false);
   const [feedback, setFeedback] = useState(`Click buy to mint your NFT.`);
   const [mintAmount, setMintAmount] = useState(1);
   const [CONFIG, SET_CONFIG] = useState({
     CONTRACT_ADDRESS: "",
     SCAN_LINK: "",
     NETWORK: {
       NAME: "",
       SYMBOL: "",
       ID: 4,
     },
     NFT_NAME: "",
     SYMBOL: "",
     MAX_SUPPLY: 1,
     WEI_FREE_MINT_COST: 0,
     DISPLAY_FREE_MINT_COST: 0,
     WEI_PUBLIC_COST: 0,
     DISPLAY_PUBLIC_COST: 0,
     GAS_LIMIT: 0,
     MARKETPLACE: "",
     MARKETPLACE_LINK: "",
     SHOW_BACKGROUND: false,
   });

     const FreeMint = () => {
       let freeMintCost = CONFIG.WEI_FREE_MINT_COST;
       let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
       let totalFreeMintCostWei = String(freeMintCost * mintAmount);
       let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount);
         console.log("Cost: ", totalFreeMintCostWei);
         console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
         setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
         setClaimingNft(true);
         blockchain.smartContract.methods
         .freeMint(mintAmount)
         .send({
             gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
             to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
             from: blockchain.account,
             value: totalFreeMintCostWei,
         })
         .once("error", (err) => {
             console.log(err);
             setFeedback("Sorry, something went wrong please try again later.");
             setClaimingNft(false);
         })
         .then((receipt) => {
             console.log(receipt);
             setFeedback(
             `WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit Opensea.io to view it.`
             );
             setClaimingNft(false);
             dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
         });
   };
   
     const claimNFTs = () => {
       let publicCost = CONFIG.WEI_PUBLIC_COST;
       let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
       let totalPublicCostWei = String(publicCost * mintAmount);
       let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount);
         console.log("Cost: ", totalPublicCostWei);
         console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
         setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
         setClaimingNft(true);
         blockchain.smartContract.methods
         .mint(mintAmount)
         .send({
             gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
             to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
             from: blockchain.account,
             value: totalPublicCostWei,
         })
         .once("error", (err) => {
             console.log(err);
             setFeedback("Sorry, something went wrong please try again later.");
             setClaimingNft(false);
         })
         .then((receipt) => {
             console.log(receipt);
             setFeedback(
             `WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit Opensea.io to view it.`
             );
             setClaimingNft(false);
             dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
         });
   };

   
   const decrementMintAmount = () => {
     let newMintAmount = mintAmount - 1;
     if (newMintAmount < 1) {
       newMintAmount = 1;
     }
     setMintAmount(newMintAmount);
   };

   const incrementMintAmount = () => {
     let newMintAmount = mintAmount + 1;
     if (newMintAmount > 10) {
       newMintAmount = 10;
     }
     setMintAmount(newMintAmount);
   };

   const getData = () => {
     if (blockchain.account !== "" && blockchain.smartContract !== null) {
       dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
     }
   };

   const getConfig = async () => {
     const configResponse = await fetch("/config/config.json", {
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         Accept: "application/json",
       },
     });
     const config = await configResponse.json();
     SET_CONFIG(config);
   };

   useEffect(() => {
     getConfig();
   }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
     getData();
   }, [blockchain.account]);

   return (
     <s.Screen>
       <s.Container
         flex={1}
         ai={"center"}
         style={{ padding: 24, backgroundColor: "var(--primary)" }}
         image={CONFIG.SHOW_BACKGROUND ? "/config/images/bg.png" : null}
       >
         <StyledLogo alt={"logo"} src={"/config/images/logo.png"} />
         <s.SpacerSmall />
         <ResponsiveWrapper flex={1} style={{ padding: 24 }} test>
           <s.Container flex={1} jc={"center"} ai={"center"}>
             <StyledImg alt={"example"} src={"/config/images/example.gif"} />
           </s.Container>
           <s.SpacerLarge />
           <s.Container
             flex={2}
             jc={"center"}
             ai={"center"}
             style={{
               backgroundColor: "var(--accent)",
               padding: 24,
               borderRadius: 24,
               border: "4px dashed var(--secondary)",
               boxShadow: "0px 5px 11px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",
             }}
           >
             <s.TextTitle
               style={{
                 textAlign: "center",
                 fontSize: 50,
                 fontWeight: "bold",
                 color: "var(--accent-text)",
               }}
             >
               {data.totalSupply} / {CONFIG.MAX_SUPPLY}
             </s.TextTitle>
             <s.TextDescription
               style={{
                 textAlign: "center",
                 color: "var(--primary-text)",
               }}
             >
               <StyledLink target={"_blank"} href={CONFIG.SCAN_LINK}>
                 {truncate(CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS, 50)}
               </StyledLink>
             </s.TextDescription>
             <s.SpacerSmall />
             {Number(data.totalSupply) >= CONFIG.MAX_SUPPLY ? (
               <>
                 <s.TextTitle
                   style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "var(--accent-text)" }}
                 >
                   The sale has ended.
                 </s.TextTitle>
                 <s.TextDescription
                   style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "var(--accent-text)" }}
                 >
                   You can still find {CONFIG.NFT_NAME} on
                 </s.TextDescription>
                 <s.SpacerSmall />
                 <StyledLink target={"_blank"} href={CONFIG.MARKETPLACE_LINK}>
                   {CONFIG.MARKETPLACE}
                 </StyledLink>
               </>
             ) : (
               <>
                 <s.TextTitle
                   style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "var(--accent-text)" }}
                 >
                   1 {CONFIG.SYMBOL} costs {CONFIG.DISPLAY_COST}{" "}
                   {CONFIG.NETWORK.SYMBOL}.
                 </s.TextTitle>
                 <s.SpacerXSmall />
                 <s.TextDescription
                   style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "var(--accent-text)" }}
                 >
                   Excluding gas fees. 
                   {feedback}
                 </s.TextDescription>
                 <s.SpacerSmall />
                 {blockchain.account === "" ||
                 blockchain.smartContract === null ? (
                   <s.Container ai={"center"} jc={"center"}>
                     <s.TextDescription
                       style={{
                         textAlign: "center",
                         color: "var(--accent-text)",
                       }}
                     >
                       Connect to the {CONFIG.NETWORK.NAME} network
                     </s.TextDescription>
                     <s.SpacerSmall />
                     <StyledButton
                       
                       onClick={(e) => {
                         e.preventDefault();
                         dispatch(connect());
                         getData();
                       }}
                     >
                       CONNECT
                     </StyledButton>
                     {blockchain.errorMsg !== "" ? (
                       <>
                         <s.SpacerSmall />
                         <s.TextDescription
                           style={{
                             textAlign: "center",
                             color: "var(--accent-text)",
                           }}
                         >
                           {blockchain.errorMsg}
                         </s.TextDescription>
                       </>
                     ) : null}
                   </s.Container>
                 ) : (
                   <>
                     <s.TextDescription
                       style={{
                         textAlign: "center",
                         color: "var(--accent-text)",
                       }}
                     >
                     </s.TextDescription>
                     <s.SpacerMedium />
                     <s.Container ai={"center"} jc={"center"} fd={"row"}>
                       <StyledRoundButton
                         style={{ lineHeight: 0.4 }}
                         disabled={claimingNft ? 1 : 0}
                         onClick={(e) => {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           decrementMintAmount();
                         }}
                       >
                         -
                       </StyledRoundButton>
                       <s.SpacerMedium />
                       <s.TextDescription
                         style={{
                           textAlign: "center",
                           color: "var(--accent-text)",
                         }}
                       >
                         {mintAmount}
                       </s.TextDescription>
                       <s.SpacerMedium />
                       <StyledRoundButton
                         disabled={claimingNft ? 1 : 0}
                         onClick={(e) => {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           incrementMintAmount();
                         }}
                       >
                         +
                       </StyledRoundButton>
                     </s.Container>
                     <s.SpacerSmall />
                     <s.Container ai={"center"} jc={"center"} fd={"row"}>
                       <StyledButton
                         
                         disabled={claimingNft ? 1 : 0}
                         onClick={(e) => {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           FreeMint();
                           getData();
                         }}
                       >
                         {claimingNft ? "BUSY" : "BUY"}
                       </StyledButton>
                     </s.Container>
                   </>
                 )}
               </>
             )}
             <s.SpacerMedium />
           </s.Container>
           <s.SpacerLarge />
           <s.Container flex={1} jc={"center"} ai={"center"}>
             <StyledImg
               alt={"example"}
               src={"/config/images/example.gif"}
               style={{ transform: "scaleX(-1)" }}
             />
           </s.Container>
         </ResponsiveWrapper>
         <s.SpacerMedium />
         <s.Container jc={"center"} ai={"center"} style={{ width: "70%" }}>
           <s.TextDescription
             style={{
               textAlign: "center",
               color: "var(--primary-text)",
             }}
           >
             Please make sure you are connected to the right network (
             {CONFIG.NETWORK.NAME} Mainnet) and the correct address. Please note:
             Once you make the purchase, you cannot undo this action.
           </s.TextDescription>
           <s.SpacerSmall />
           <s.TextDescription
             style={{
               textAlign: "center",
               color: "var(--primary-text)",
             }}
           >
             We have set the gas limit to {CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT} for the contract to
             successfully mint your NFT. We recommend that you don't lower the
             gas limit.
           </s.TextDescription>
         </s.Container>
       </s.Container>
     </s.Screen>
   );
 }

export default App;
```

Comment: You sure you want that C++ tag? It doesn't look like the most appropriate choice for the given code example.

Comment: @user4581301 _I'm_ sure.  Removed.

Comment: I don't get also why html or css tags are there- To the op, you won't get more attention adding more tags, in fact, you'll get quite less as experts on rectjs would may not even look at your question if you are asking for css help